# CiviContribute: show contributions without other contact details

Tags: drupal, civicontribute

Been using CiviCRM with the CiviContribute extension for a good portion of this year. Would like to allow users to see their contributions from their own logins without actually having access to other details, like the notes tab specifically.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CiviCRM offers a Contact Dashboard - which you can set to show eg Event, Member, Contribution, Pledges etc (I think via Admin > Customise > Display Preferences or /civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/display?reset=1) and then you should be able to use your CMS permissions to let logged in users access this.

In drupal they get that link showing at the bottom of /user

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This answer is applicable for WordPress. If you are using a different CMS you will have to state which you are looking for.

1. Create a Page titled "Dashboard"
2. Insert this shortcode [civicrm component="user-dashboard" hijack="0"] & whatever else you want the donors to see.
3. Add plugin *WP Redirect After Login Plugin*. It is in the WP Plugin Library. https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirect-after-login/ I just change the Subscriber Role (or whatever Role your Members are defaulted to) to go to the dashboard url you just made in step 1. If you do not do this, they will land on the WP-admin dashboard.
4. Add a donor login link where you need it (yousiteurl/wp-admin/ or yoursiteurl/login/)

ps. I also use a plugin *ABD Dashboard Widget Manager* https://wordpress.org/plugins/abd-dashboard-widget-manager/ This allows you to edit what the donors see when they are in the WP Dashboard. Add widgets that redirect them back to their donation history, give them information, etc.

Comment: I always forget that CiviCRM works across all major CMS systems. I meant for drupal and have added the tag. Thanks for the detailed list though!